# Approaches/libraries to perform advanced math (e.g. calculus) in PHP?

Tags: php, math, programming-languages

We are doing a project which needs differential and integral calculus.

- *The only scripting language we have worked with is PHP.*
- We are on a shared host with *no shell access*
- The UI is made in PHP / Javascript.

We want to call from php to another script (different language) which than will return an array with the results.

Now the questions:

1. **Which language is easiest to connect to PHP in a non-shell environment?** (is it really only perl)
2. Which language (considering the filter of question 1) has best support of math libraries or frameworks to easily our work?
3. Which language (C is not an option, as per above) has good performance in doing heavy calculations?

Thanks for your suggestions

**UPDATE:**

RUBY ON RAILS has such a library
http://rubyforge.org/projects/integral/

*Rails is on some shared hosts included (like mine) to use.*

For Perl exists a book Higher-order Perl: A Guide To Program Transformation,

Comment: I second Jack Maney's solution. While there is "connection overhead" (and $), it really was a tool designed for this sort of task.

Comment: @Email It doesn't matter if Perl can be called easily. You're **still in the same boat**: that is, finding a suitable [available] library to perform the required calculations. The question has just changed to "Approaches/libraries to perform advanced math (e.g. calculus) *in Perl?*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what programming languages does your host support? you could always just upload a script of any language and call it from php using the exec command http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

matlab is good for math stuff ... you could also do python and import some math libraries 
(Im a big fan of python)

Comment: we are hosted by hos_tgator so we have cgi/perl easiest to use. No clue how to make use of other languages like python. The word "Easiest" at the question should be set emphasis to.

Answer (score 1):

Investigating [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/) is probably worth a few minutes if your time.

Comment: +1 thx. having a deeper look. Sadly python means at least a vps, dedi or win server ... i guess. i feel like there is no easy solution like i dreamed about. its a non-profit college project. my webhost told me that i could use php, perl or ruby(-on-rails) only. But according to the reaction here it seems to be really stupid to use those, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The **PHP/Java** bridge might be something, if it is available.